# Applescript: number list of words according to their occurrence in the sequence

Tags: applescript

So I have this list of words:

```
{"It", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times", "it", "was", "the", "worst", "of", "times", "it", "was", "the", "age", "of", "wisdom", "it", "was", "the", "age", "of", "foolishness", "it", "was", "the", "epoch", "of", "belief"}
```

I'd like each occurrence of a word to be numbered according to the number of times it has occurred in the sequence:

```
{"It", 1}, {"was", 1}, {"the", 1}, {"best", 1}, {"of", 1}, {"times", 1} {"it", 2}, {"was", 2}, {"the", 2}, {"worst", 1}, {"of", 2}, {"times", 2}, {"it", 3}, {"was", 3}, {"the", 3}, {"age", 1}, {"of", 3}, {"wisdom", 1}, {"it", 4}, {"was", 4}, {"the", 4}, etc.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In case you're wondering about the down-votes: This is your 2nd question, and again you've demonstrated no effort to solve the problem yourself and are just asking that the solution be given to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppleScript is not the right tool for this job, so while the following solution works, it is sloooow.

(For better performance, you'd need full hash-table functionality, which AppleScript doesn't provide - AppleScript's `record` class is severely handicapped by the inability to specify keys *dynamically*, at runtime, via variables - third-party solutions exist, though (e.g., http://www.latenightsw.com/freeware/list-record-tools/)).

```applescript
# Helper handler: Given a search word, returns the number of times the word 
# already occurs in the specified list (as the first sub-item of each list item).
on countOccurrences(searchWrd, lst)
  local counter
  set counter to 0
  repeat with wordNumPair in lst
    if item 1 of wordNumPair is searchWrd then
      set counter to counter + 1
    end if
  end repeat
  return counter
end countOccurrences

# Define the input list.
set inList to {"It", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times", "it", "was", "the", "worst", "of", "times", "it", "was", "the", "age", "of", "wisdom", "it", "was", "the", "age", "of", "foolishness", "it", "was", "the", "epoch", "of", "belief"}

# Initialize the output list.
set outList to {}

# Loop over the input list and build the output list incrementally.
repeat with wrd in inList
  # Note that `contents of` returns the string content of the list item
  # (dereferences the object specifier that `repeat with` returns).
  set outList to outList & {{contents of wrd, 1 + (my countOccurrences(contents of wrd, outList))}}
end repeat

# outList now contains the desired result.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and I appologies for not trying to solve the problem myself.

Comment: @user3803526: You're welcome. For _everyone's_ benefit I encourage you to show some effort when posting a question: _you_ will learn by trying to solve the problem yourself, and, if you do, others are more likely to help you, and in turn even others may benefit from answers given.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it...

```
# Define the input list.
set inList to {"It", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times", "it", "was", "the", "worst", "of", "times", "it", "was", "the", "age", "of", "wisdom", "it", "was", "the", "age", "of", "foolishness", "it", "was", "the", "epoch", "of", "belief"}
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set inListLF to inList as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}

set usedList to {}
set resultList to {}
repeat with aWord in inList
    set aWord to contents of aWord
    considering case
        if aWord is not in usedList then
            set end of usedList to aWord
            set end of resultList to aWord & " - " & (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of inListLF & " | grep -o " & quoted form of aWord & " | wc -l")
        end if
    end considering
end repeat

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set resultList to resultList as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
return resultList
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but it solves a _different_ problem: the OP's desired output is an _ongoing_ count of the occurrences _so far_ (with the output list mirroring the input list word for word, including duplicates); also (two things that can easily be corrected), the elements of your output list are not lists, and your matching is case-_sensitive_, whereas the OP's output shows case-INsensitive matching.