# Applescript: number each sublist of a list containing a word according to the occurrence of that word in the list

Tags: applescript

I have a list like this:

```
 {{"269", "It"}, {"439", "was"}, {"509", "the"}, {"829", "best"}, {"1059", "of"}, {"1350", "times"}, {"1449", "it"}, {"2089", "was"}, {"2659", "the"}, {"3250", "worst"}, {"3429", "of"}, {"3529", "times"}, {"4219", "it"}, {"4519", "was"}, {"5210", "the"}, {"5629", "age"}, {"6049", "of"}, {"6279", "wisdom"}, {"6599", "it"}, {"6659", "was"}, {"6839", "the"}, {"7399", "age"}, {"of"}, {"7639", "foolishness"}, {"8019", "it"}, {"8619", "was"}, {"9369", "the"}, {"9477", "epoch"}, {"9682", "of"}, {"9897", "belief"}}
```

and I want it to also have number associated with each occurrence of each word in sequence:

```
{{"269", "It", 1}, {"439", "was", 1}, {"509", "the", 1}, {"829", "best", 1}, {"1059", "of", 1}, {"1350", "times", 1}, {"1449", "it", 2}, {"2089", "was", 2}, {"2659", "the", 2}, {"3250", "worst", 1}, {"3429", "of", 2}, {"3529", "times", 2}, {"4219", "it", 3}, {"4519", "was", 3}, {"5210", "the", 3}, {"5629", "age", 1}, {"6049", "of", 3}, {"6279", "wisdom", 1}, {"6599", "it", 4}, {"6659", "was", 4}, {"6839", "the", 4}, {"7399", "age", 2}, {"of" 4}, {"7639", "foolishness", 1}, {"8019", "it", 4}, {"8619", "was", 5}, {"9369", "the", 5}, {"9477", "epoch", 1}, {"9682", "of", 5}, {"9897", "belief", 1}}
```

I tried to modify the script mklement0 gave me like this:

```
set inList to {{"269", "It"}, {"439", "was"}, {"509", "the"}, {"829", "best"}, {"1059", "of"}, {"1350", "times"}, {"1449", "it"}, {"2089", "was"}, {"2659", "the"}, {"3250", "worst"}, {"3429", "of"}, {"3529", "times"}, {"4219", "it"}, {"4519", "was"}, {"5210", "the"}, {"5629", "age"}, {"6049", "of"}, {"6279", "wisdom"}, {"6599", "it"}, {"6659", "was"}, {"6839", "the"}, {"7399", "age"}, {"of"}, {"7639", "foolishness"}, {"8019", "it"}, {"8619", "was"}, {"9369", "the"}, {"9477", "epoch"}, {"9682", "of"}, {"9897", "belief"}}
set word_list to {}
repeat with i from 1 to (length of inList)
    set the_word to item i of inList
    if item 2 of the_word is word then
        set outList to outList & {{contents of the_word, 1 + (my countOccurrences(contents of inList, word_list))}}
    end if
end repeat
```

It give me an error:
    "Can’t get item 2 of {\"of\"}." number -1728 from item 2 of {"of"}

Clearly I don't even know where to start for this one.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You have and element in your data that has only one item {"of"} its getting an error because it's trying to read item 2, that does not exist. You can either fix the data or put in a condition to ignore anything with less than 2 items.

Comment: Thanks! Nonetheless my syntax is still screwed up. After giving {"of"} a value it still fails to give me the desired result.

Comment: add the currentOccurrences function to your question too so we can see.

Comment: what is the desired result ?

Comment: The original `countOccurrences` handler is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24582995/45375. @user3803526: I encourage you to create [MCVEs (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set inList to {{"269", "It"}, {"439", "was"}, {"509", "the"}, {"829", "best"}, {"1059", "of"}, {"1350", "times"}, {"1449", "it"}, {"2089", "was"}, {"2659", "the"}, {"3250", "worst"}, {"3429", "of"}, {"3529", "times"}, {"4219", "it"}, {"4519", "was"}, {"5210", "the"}, {"5629", "age"}, {"6049", "of"}, {"6279", "wisdom"}, {"6599", "it"}, {"6659", "was"}, {"6839", "the"}, {"7399", "age"}, {"7639", "foolishness"}, {"8019", "it"}, {"8619", "was"}, {"9369", "the"}, {"9477", "epoch"}, {"9682", "of"}, {"9897", "belief"}}

my occurencInSubList(inList, 2) -- first param : a list of subLists, second param : index of the word in each subList
inList -- the results are in inList.

on occurencInSubList(L, n)
    set dupeList to {}
    set tc to length of L -- numbers of subList
    repeat with i from 1 to tc
        set the_word to item n of list i of L -- get the second item in this sublist
        if the_word is not in dupeList then -- to not counting the occurrences of the same word again.
            set end of dupeList to the_word
            set cnt to 1
            repeat with j from i to tc -- count the occurrences of this word once
                tell list j of L to if item n = the_word then
                    set end to cnt --- add an item (the count ) at the end of this subList
                    set cnt to cnt + 1
                end if
            end repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end occurencInSubList
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version adapted to your new input-list format from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24582995/45375):

Note: As @adamh pointed out in a comment, your input list was malformed in that it was missing the first sub-list item for one of the `"of"` sub-lists - I simply inserted `"0"` in my code below.

```applescript
# Helper handler: Given a search word, returns the number of times the word 
# already occurs in the specified list (as the 2nd sub-item of each list item).
on countOccurrences(searchWrd, lst)
  local counter
  set counter to 0
  repeat with subList in lst
    if item 2 of subList is searchWrd then
      set counter to counter + 1
    end if
  end repeat
  return counter
end countOccurrences

# Define the input list.
set inList to {{"269", "It"}, {"439", "was"}, {"509", "the"}, {"829", "best"}, {"1059", "of"}, {"1350", "times"}, {"1449", "it"}, {"2089", "was"}, {"2659", "the"}, {"3250", "worst"}, {"3429", "of"}, {"3529", "times"}, {"4219", "it"}, {"4519", "was"}, {"5210", "the"}, {"5629", "age"}, {"6049", "of"}, {"6279", "wisdom"}, {"6599", "it"}, {"6659", "was"}, {"6839", "the"}, {"7399", "age"}, {"0", "of"}, {"7639", "foolishness"}, {"8019", "it"}, {"8619", "was"}, {"9369", "the"}, {"9477", "epoch"}, {"9682", "of"}, {"9897", "belief"}}

# Initialize the output list.
set outList to {}

# Loop over the input list and build the output list incrementally.
repeat with subList in inList
  set outList to outList & ¬
    {subList & 1 + (my countOccurrences(item 2 of subList, outList))}
end repeat
```